# Docker build fails with error: failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1

Tags: windows, docker

We're in the middle of trying to update a bunch of Docker builds from Windows 2016 to Windows 2019 so that we can upgrade our Service Fabric cluster from Windows 2016 to Windows 2019, and also so we can upgrade from .NET Core 2.2 which is end-of-life to .NET Core 3.1 which has LTS support.

Docker images for .NET Core 3.1 are not provided for Windows 2016 which is making the upgrade more difficult. Our current issue is that on the Windows 2019 build nodes, we are seeing about a 33% failure rate of docker builds due to an intermittent error when doing a docker build (thus a docker pull) of:

> ERROR: for sdk  failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit
>   status 1: output: ProcessUtilityVMImage
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\1ca28cd86a3256aeff525cb4933d34059f2baae2b223e572bc5dc321ed1e3175\UtilityVM:
>   Incorrect function. failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit
>   status 1: output: ProcessUtilityVMImage
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\1ca28cd86a3256aeff525cb4933d34059f2baae2b223e572bc5dc321ed1e3175\UtilityVM:
>   Incorrect function.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a Windows version specific problem, as similar issue has been reported by many people using Windows 10 1903. After doing some Google search, looks like the problem can be solved by removing some CBFS drivers that certain apllications install on the system.

Following links might be helpful as they report similar issues:

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3884

https://github.com/microsoft/hcsshim/issues/624